Athena Iceberg does not delete orphan files
I have Athena Iceberg table.
The table has 2 partitions.
Each hour I update it with MERGE
I also do  DELETE command daily to clean up everything inserted earlier than 7 days.
SELECT count(*) FROM "my_table$files"

now gives 16. Meanwhile data folder contains 158 files.
None of
VACUUM  my_table

or
OPTIMIZE my_table REWRITE DATA USING BIN_PACK

Is not helping to remove unnecessary files.
Table has following TBLPROPERTIES
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'table_type'='iceberg',
  'vacuum_max_snapshot_age_seconds'='60',
  'write_compression'='ZSTD',
  'format'='parquet',
  'vacuum_max_metadata_files_to_keep'='2',
  'optimize_rewrite_delete_file_threshold'='2',
  'optimize_rewrite_data_file_threshold'='2'
)

It is that aggressive because I do not need any history of changes. I'm interested in the latest state only.
Number of files is keep growing and never decrease, the spite the fact that the number of rows in the table is almost constant.
What I'm doing wrong, and how to stop files inflation.
BTW
When I manually delete from the data directory anything that is not listed in the files query result I have following error on any random select.
ICEBERG_CANNOT_OPEN_SPLIT: Error opening Iceberg split s3://my_bucket/data_lake/my_table/data/lOlxRw/20240801_100037_00009_4atvz-e01ed1f7-ec42-4841-a13a-461c597951f4.parquet (offset=0, length=16462): io.trino.hdfs.s3.TrinoS3FileSystem$UnrecoverableS3OperationException: com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: The specified key does not exist.

